# Google app engine running error

Tags: google-app-engine

When I was trying to run one of the application on google app engine I keep on getting a yell icon the means error. How can I fix it ,so I can run my application.

The error is one the left end side of hello-udacity

Here is the link of the picture of the error: https://plus.google.com/u/1/115545843446144625696/posts/aoRyoN2r2Sd?pid=6168940381509733874&oid=115545843446144625696

In main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello udacity!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], 
                                debug=True)
```

---

In app.yaml

```
application: hello-udacity

version: 1

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes


handlers:

- url: /favicon\.ico


 static_files: favicon.ico

  upload: favicon\.ico


- url: .*

  script: main.app


libraries:

- name: webapp2

version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: what did you get in logs?

Comment: i add whats in the logs

Answer (score 0):

The `app.yaml` file uses the [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) syntax and so your `app.yaml` should comply with those. The following is a clearer configuration

```
application: hello-udacity
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

For more on this see [about app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_About_app_yaml) in the developer docs